# Change http / https protocol in browser settings

Tags: http, browser, https, protocols, settings

I changed it in the browser settings for a long time (I just don’t remember how) so that in the address of the pages it was always addressed as https (even if it was specified - http) after pressing Enter. Tell me how to change https to http in the Chrome settings and in ie11?

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by HSTS - HTTP Strict Transport Security. When a website sends this header in a response, then the browser will use a secure connection even if you explicitly specify http:// as the protocol.

This response header looks like this: `Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000`

If this is the case, to clear those settings in Chrome you can go to the following address:

`chrome://net-internals/#hsts`

and try to modify entries for the domain you need within that panel.